# Trying to restore SQL Server 2012 Express to 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble restoring a database backup from my current host (SQL Server 2012 Express) to my new host (SQL Server 2014).

I am using MyLittleBackup and it is reporting the error below.

There seems to be duplicate MDF files in the script it runs.

Why are there duplicates and how can I fix it?

> .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\rbkkipfb_xxx_data.mdf'
>   is claimed by 'ftrow_Products and Brands'(3) and 'xxx_dat'(1).
>   The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files. File
>   'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\rbkkipfb_xxx_data.mdf'
>   is claimed by 'ftrow_ProductsAndBrands'(4) and 'xxx_dat'(1).
>   The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> USE [master] GO
>
> ALTER DATABASE [rbkkipfb_xxx] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK
>   IMMEDIATE GO
>
> RESTORE DATABASE [rbkkipfb_xxx] FROM
>   DISK=N'C:\inetpub\mylittlebackup\data\MLBUpload\MSSQL\rbkkipfb_xxx\636124445992698861_xxx.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY , FILE=1 , REPLACE , MOVE N'ftrow_ProductsAndBrands' TO
>   N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA**rbkkipfb_xxx_data**.mdf'
>   , MOVE N'ftrow_Products and Brands' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA**rbkkipfb_xxx_data**.mdf'
>   , MOVE N'xxx_dat' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA**rbkkipfb_xxx_data**.mdf'
>   , MOVE N'xxx_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\rbkkipfb_xxx_log.ldf'
>   , NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10 GO
>
> ALTER DATABASE [rbkkipfb_xxx] MODIFY FILE
>   (NAME=N'ftrow_ProductsAndBrands', MAXSIZE=10485760KB ) GO
>
> ALTER DATABASE [rbkkipfb_xxx] MODIFY FILE
>   (NAME=N'xxx_log', MAXSIZE=10485760KB ) GO
>
> ALTER DATABASE [rbkkipfb_xxx] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK
>   IMMEDIATE GO

Edit: I think this is due to full text indexes, can I restore without them?

Answer (score 0):

I have had to restore databases with full-text, I don't know any way to NOT restore them.

You could try removing the indexes from the source database backup, doing another backup, and then doing your restore.

Comment: How do you remove from source backup and do you mean the bak file? The original database is no longer available...

Comment: Oh.  I don't know of a way to do that.  I was thinking the original db was available, where you could delete the indexes from, and create a new backup.

Comment: Thanks for your replies... But are you saying that the database backup is of no use whatsoever?

Comment: If you need to remove the full text indexes first, then I think your out of luck.  I assume that you tried changing the restore location \ file names with the restore wizard.

Comment: I can't change the restore options with the tools available to me and even using SMSS I don't have the permissions necessary to do a restore and access the file system.

Comment: I am sorry to say then, I don't think there is an answer for you.  Can someone with permissions to the server help you?